# How can I communicate with Celery on Cloud Foundry?

Tags: python, debugging, celery, cloud-foundry

I have a wsgi app with a celery component. Basically, when certain requests come in they can hand off relatively time-consuming tasks to celery. I have a working version of this product on a server I set up myself, but our client recently asked me to deploy it to Cloud Foundry. Since Celery is not available as a service on Cloud Foundry, we (me and the client's deployment team) decided to deploy the app *twice* – once as a wsgi app and once as a standalone celery app, sharing a rabbitmq service.

The code between the apps is identical. The wsgi app responds correctly, returning the expected web pages. `vmc logs celeryapp` shows that celery is to be up-and-running, but when I send requests to wsgi that should become celery tasks, they disappear as soon as they get to a `.delay()` statement. They neither appear in the celery logs nor do they appear as an error.

### Attempts to debug:

- I can't use `celery.contrib.rdb` in Cloud Foundry (to supply a telnet interface to pdb), as each app is sandboxed and port-restricted.
- I don't know how to find the specific rabbitmq instance these apps are supposed to share, so I can see what messages it's passing.

Update: to corroborate the above statement about finding rabbitmq, here's what happens when I try to access the node that should be sharing celery tasks:

```
root@cf:~# export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=eecef185-e1ae-4e08-91af-47f590304ecc
root@cf:~# export RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=57390
root@cf:~# ~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rabbitmq/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues
Listing queues ...

=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Jun-2012::11:31:35 ===
Error in process <0.36.0> on node 'rabbitmqctl17951@cf' with exit value: {badarg,[{erlang,list_to_existing_atom,["eecef185-e1ae-4e08-91af-47f590304ecc@localhost"]},{dist_util,recv_challenge,1},{dist_util,handshake_we_started,1}]}

Error: unable to connect to node 'eecef185-e1ae-4e08-91af-47f590304ecc@cf': nodedown
diagnostics:
- nodes and their ports on cf: [{'eecef185-e1ae-4e08-91af-47f590304ecc',57390},
                                {rabbitmqctl17951,36032}]
- current node: rabbitmqctl17951@cf
- current node home dir: /home/cf
- current node cookie hash: 1igde7WRgkhAea8fCwKncQ==
```

How can I debug this and/or why are my tasks vanishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was caused by a deadlock between the broker and the celery worker, such that the worker would never acknowledge the task as complete, and never accept a new task, but never crashed or failed either. The tasks weren't vanishing; they were simply staying in queue forever.

Update: The deadlock was caused by the fact that we were running celeryd inside a wrapper script that installed dependencies. (Literally `pip install -r requirements.txt && ./celeryd -lINFO`). Because of how Cloud Foundry manages process trees, Cloud Foundry would try to kill the parent process (bash), which would HUP celeryd, but ultimately lots of child processes would never die.